# My whereJsonContains not working (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my laravel query.

Now I use query like this:

`$courses = Course::whereJsonContains('schedule->day', 1)->get();`

It doesn't work.

I'm using postgreSql 9.6 and my database and raw query look like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/88fd2/1/0

I want to select class where have schedule in day = 1

Comment: `whereJsonContains` assumes `schedule->day` is an array of integers. In your case its a property of a parent array.

Answer (score 3):

If you define the column as `schedule->day`, MySQL assumes that this is an array of integers. In your case it's an array of objects, so you have to target the parent array and add the property name you are looking for in the second argument.

Like so:

```
$courses = Course::whereJsonContains('schedule', ['day' => 1])->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved with

`$courses = Course::whereJsonContains('schedule', [['day' => '1']])->get();`

Answer (score 1):

I solved with

```
$products=ProductShop::active()
          ->whereJsonContains('tag', [['value' => "tampa"]])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're querying the value уоu don't need to use `whereJsonContains`, simply use a regular `where` query such as:

```
$courses = Course::where('schedule->day', 1)->get();`
```

If you want to check if `day` exists in Json:

```
$courses = Course::where('schedule->day', '!=', '')->get();
```